# Redis service won't restart after reboot

Tags: 18.04, services, log, redis

After an upgrade of my server (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). The Redis service refused to start:

```
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-04-19 22:07:22 CEST; 37s ago
  Process: 5644 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 5644 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: redis.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 22:07:22 vps systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

I tried to start the server manually and it worked (as sudo). Then I tried with the redis user I got:

```
[22:05:05] root@vps:/var/log# sudo -u redis /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
  5533:C 19 Apr 22:05:45.755 # Fatal error, can't open config file '/etc/redis/redis.conf'
```

I have identified the same error in the syslog:

```
Apr 19 21:27:31 vps redis-server[1246]: 1246:C 19 Apr 21:27:30.067 # Fatal error, can't open config file '/etc/redis/redis.conf'
```

I gave the right to the file to the redis user and the service now starts correctly.

What I don't understand is that this file wasn't modified since 2016 (the user what root before I gave the right to the redis user):

```
[22:16:37] root@vps:/etc/redis# ll /etc/redis/redis.conf
-rw-r----- 1 redis redis 46716 Dec 24  2016 /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

I don't know what had happened. I already reboot a lot of time and never encountered this error. I'd like to know the root cause, so it doesn't happen again because all the hosted websites are down when it happens. If you have any idea, I could investigate. Thank you.